# XCode code siging error XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, code-signing-certificate

When I try to run my application on a simulator, everything works fine. But when I try to build it to test it on a real device, I get the following error:

```
CodeSign /Users/fvoordeckers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-##########/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.xctest
cd /Users/fvoordeckers/Documents/Projecten/MyProject/iOS
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Frederik (########)"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign ##################/Users/fvoordeckers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-##########/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.xctest

/Users/fvoordeckers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-##########/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.xctest: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I've changed IDs with `#`. I created a provisioning profile that includes the device I'm using and al the required certificates. It doesn't seem to have a problem with the app but with the xctest... I also tried adding the '--deep' flag to the signing configuration but it didn't help...

Comment: Did you change your build settings at the project level, at the app target level or at the test target level ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to **Edit Scheme** in xcode -> In **Build Target** -> Remove **MyProject.xctest** completely or ***uncheck*** all the boxes of MyProject.xctest *Analyze , Test etc..*

**Clean your project and then Run on the device**.

Comment: if I don't have **`MyProject.xctest`** but still getting the same error ?

Comment: Can you explain why this is?

Comment: Thanks – I can confirm that, if you neglect to clean the build, then even if you untick various boxes, this error will still persist. Cleaning the build gets you past the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue and nothing helped (updating the schemes, changing the provisioning profiles or code signing identity, etc.) **except** updating Xcode to its latest beta version: **Xcode 7.3 Beta 4**.

I guess Apple did some major improvements in this new version :)