# Code sign error : bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, code-signing

Im working on an iOS app, Swift language, iOS8, Xcode 6.1. It was running fine on the iPad. Then I added a "Resource" folder reference to the project, after which I am getting the Code sign error.

The Resource folder contains some HTML files. I am not sure how this folder reference is causing this problem. Any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 94, accepted):

OK, solved it, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26617294/1029360) helped me.

I renamed the folder. Apparently Xcode does not like "Resources" file to be created manually.

Comment: Oh man you are awesome, I renamed it to Resources2 and it worked

Comment: rename made same behaviour like deleting Derived Data. It's just recreate Derived Data in new folder

Comment: Hard to belive it's still a problem in 2019

Comment: How is this answer (the correct one!) somehow the 13th one down in the list?!

Comment: works! how strange

Comment: still works in Dec 2021!  On the other hand Apple Document tell us to use "Resources" folder ...

Answer (score 62):

I have had this issue in two different projects, I done alot of the suggested stuff, cleared the DerivedData folder, re-installed pods etc.

In both projects it was complaining about a particular Pod and being unable to codesign it.

What fixed it for me was:

1. Select the Pods Project
2. In the main editor window, select the Pod in the targets dropdown
3. Under the general tab, and under the identity header, click choose Info.plist file
4. Select the plist file for the Pod

The project should now build. For some reason it seems to lose this setting, or not be able to reference it's own plist file.

This worked for me in both projects. Not 100% sure why, but I hope it helps someone else having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue and saved me a lot of trouble updating a complex cocoa pods configuration to the latest version.

Comment: Unfortunately, iTunes is giving me a bunch of related errors when I try to upload, so I'll probably just have to update CocoaPods.

Comment: If there is no Info.plist just take any other bundle Info.plist, chances are it will work.

Comment: The above steps followed by a Clean operation worked for me.

Comment: 2017, yet another release of Xcode, and even more unexplainable Build problems...  Are they ever going to make this mess... developer-friendly...?  Thanks for these tips, this made my Build error go away..!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your simple solution worked perfect for me

Answer (score 34):

I have the same issue for some hours. But the following helped me.

1. Delete Derived data
2. Clean the project

Then running again, worked.

Comment: I don't know why, but that's true, I have to delete Derived Data every time there is an iOS update.

Comment: Just cleaning the build helped in my case :)
10x

Answer (score 16):

Just in case someone else is having this issue: Make sure you didn't add a **Static Framework** into the "**Embedded Binaries**" section, only Dynamic Frameworks are required to be there.

Answer (score 10):

Clean Build Folder fixed this for me.

Comment: Using XCode is starting to feel like Windows ("just restart, that might fix it")

Comment: worse than windows

Answer (score 4):

Happened with me after a week of updating to Xcode 8.1, turns out I had to update cocoapods (sudo gem update cocoapods) and do pod install again to get it working.

Comment: i have tried everything, but only updating cocoapods and installing the pods again worked!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old thread, but I just encountered this issue and none of the other answers helped.  For me, this error occurred upon "Embed & Sign" of an old third-party framework, which I don't own.  Looking inside that `.framework` bundle, it did indeed have an incorrect [directory format](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html): the `Versions/A/` directory was instead named `Versions/1.0.0/` (the "1.0.0" of course being an arbitrary version number), which seems to confuse the `CodeSign` command.  So I did `cd Versions` into the framework's directory, then `mv 1.0.0 A` and `ln -sf A Current` - after which the CodeSign and build succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to accepted answer I thought I should add this-

For me I am getting this error because Xcode-8 is actually using Test Target while running app on device. So if its the same then follow these steps:

Go to Edit Scheme in xcode -> In Build Target -> Remove MyProject.xctest completely or uncheck all the boxes of MyProject.xctest Analyze , Test etc..

Clean your project and then Run on the device.

PS: Answer is from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482680/xcode-code-siging-error-xctest)

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was, in the info.plist, i forgot to update the url scheme to new bundle id

previous : com.test.app
new : com.test.app1

this fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

solved here

- make sure all frameworks used added to Embed Frameworks section in in build phases
- keep copy only when installing CHECKED on same section

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Problem started after upgrading to Xcode 8.1. My project utilizes CocoaPods. I had to delete the `./Pods` dir and run `pod install` and `pod update` (which updated Flurry-iOS-SDK to 7.8.1). Why? Because reasons.

Answer (score 0):

for me, after I upgraded my xcode to 8.1, similar problems occur. I have tried different ways, but seems update cocoapods to the lastest version is definitely worth to do at first. And then update pods with
`pod install --verbose --no-repo-update` and 
`pod update --verbose --no-repo-update` would help.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this issue after updating to Xcode 8.1. Simply updating cocoapods (by running 'sudo gem update cocoapods' in Terminal) fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For someone who like me, all the above solution can't work. You can double check your scheme name, there shouldn't be any space in there. Cocoapods can't handle scheme name with space with version 1.1.1. But I'm not sure why this happen only when I upgrade to Xcode 8.2. It worked pretty fine with Xcode 8.1.

It took me hours to figure out the issue. 
You can follow this [thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5742)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue now and it has been actually caused by Fabric's Embed script and resolved by removing a space inside path to project file.

Having a perfectly buildable workspace in project folder called 'app-ios' I have made a copy named 'app-ios 2' and it was not possible to build that. codesign did report `bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable` and respective path was not to the bundle, but ended with `/app-ios` instead of `app-ios 2/DerivedData/...`

After renaming the folder to `app-ios-2` the workspace is buildable again.

Comment: I think you should give more details for your answer to be helpufl.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after unsuccessfully trying practically all solutions reported here, I found that simply **deleting the product file** (i.e. moving it to the trash in Finder) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the problem on an app targeting MacOS (not iOS) using AppCode, but I believe that solution should work for all cases: In AppCode, just do a `Run > Clean` before you build.