# Xcode: Code Signing Error Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

My app was running fine until when i changed Apple distribution/development provision certificates cause i re-created a new Account on itunes development program. After setting up everything and ending up coming across this error on xcode failing to sign some stuff on Alamofire as shown in the image below.

[image: Thrown error by xcode failing to sign the app]

Comment: Did you try to clean your project and then Rebuild ?

Comment: Yes, i tried everything it seem not to work @Arrabidas92

Comment: Also close and reopen your workspace ?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271548/code-sign-error-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable/40552524#40552524 I had similar issues and wrote up what I done to fix it

Comment: @Arrabidas92 I tried even restarting both my phone and laptop didn't work

Comment: Sorry i can't help you

Comment: @Scriptable Looking into it, will get back to with the response

Comment: have you tried clearing your derived data folder?

Comment: @Scriptable After going through your answer i kinda don't understand this part here "Under the general tab, and under the identity header, click choose Info.plist file". I did select the Pod in the targets dropdown but i can't find any Info.plist file identity header

Comment: I have exactly the same issue... and no solution seems to work...

Comment: @PAD Solved the issue by making sure that i re-installed all certificates needed for iOS development and selecting the correct provisional profile and finally perform quick clean up on derived data.

Comment: I am too facing this issue. I don't have apple developer license. could you please let me know what's causing this issue?

Comment: @Nadendla For my personal experience, I had set a different Code signing identity values located at Build Settings of my project but it never happened when i didn't have developer license. You may proceed to checkout _Scriptable_ answer.