# Upgraded to XCode 9.1, Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, upgrade

I have an existing app, and upgraded the OS on my mac High Sierra and also Xcode from 8 to 9.1. Since then, when I try to build, I am getting an error with some shell script failing.  The strangest thing is that this happens only when I try to build using my iPad device.  No problems iPhone device or simulator, and no problem with iPad simulators. I tried updating all the pod files, clearing Derived Data and similar things. Below is the screenshot with all the error info. I am a newbie to iOS programming, and any help is very much appreciated. Thank you all in advance.
[image]

Comment: this is a pods signing error, check your code signing settings in the pod that relates to `GTMSessionFetcher`

Comment: @scriptable  Could you please provide some steps on checking the code signing settings for this pod?  I am a newbie and still trying to find my ways around these.

Comment: Sure, see one of my other answers here, it shows you how to check the code signing settings for your pod. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271548/code-sign-error-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable/40552524#40552524

Comment: @Scriptable  Thank you so much for the help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical signing issue. Try delete Keychain certificates pertaining your project and rebuild using fresh ones off developer.apple.com.

Comment: How would I find the keychains pertaining to the project?

Comment: The Keychain Access app on Mac