# Submit app to appstore in xcode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to upload my app to appstore on xcode now.
I researched many things for archiving builds in xcode and almost issues are solved.
But there is still one issue. It really gives me stress.
Anyone please help me.
I'm using automatically manage signing in xcode. and Already made distribution certificate and provision.
And downloaded it to my mac and allowed codesign in keyChainAccess for the distribution provision.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify where you’re having trouble? It sounds like you have everything setup to me and just need to start the archive process. Edit - somehow missed the image! Have you tried the suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271548/code-sign-error-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Calvedos.

Comment: There are quite a few things that this could be. I edited my original comment and added a link to another answer which has a multitude of suggestions. The first thing to do is have a look at that and see if any of them solve your issue.

Comment: "I'm trying to upload my app to appstore on xcode now" With 127 warnings still outstanding? That sounds like a bad idea.